# Json Schema restrictions on Value field which can be Integer or String

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently having a JSON schema in my code

```
 {
    'type' => 'object', 'required' => true, 'additionalProperties' => false,
    'properties' => {
        'variables' => {
            'type' => 'array', 'required' => true,
            'items' => {
                'type' => 'object', 'required' => true, 'additionalProperties' => false,
                'properties' => {
                    'variable' => { 'type' => 'string', 'required' => true },
                    'value' => { 'required' => true }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am trying to put some extra validations here on value field. E.g. In case on String length should not be more than 64 chars , and in case of Integer value should be in Integer limit. how should I go about defining this schema.

Answer (score 8):

For positive integer less or equal to 1024:

```
"type": "integer",
"minimum": 0,
"maximum": 1024
```

For string to be not empty and not longer than 64 symbols:

```
"type": "string",
"pattern": "^.{1,64}$"
```

There are good explanations of all the guards [at official site](http://json-schema.org/).

Comment: The pattern should have `^` and `$` around it, or the schema validation will not always fail when it should.